# How do I write a method that can output data from any class using generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, data-binding

I'm trying to write a custom method to populate a ListView control using Generics:

```
    private void BindDataToListView(List<T> containerItems)
    {
        this.View = View.Details;
        this.GridLines = true;
        this.FullRowSelect = true;

        if (this.Items.Count > 0)
            this.Items.Clear();

        this.BeginUpdate();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in containerItems)
        {
            // do something
        }

        this.EndUpdate();
    }
```

The parameter containerItems can have many items since I'm using generics.  But I get stuck in the foreach loop.  How do I access the values in containerItems?

Do I have to use reflection on each instance of T in the foreach loop?   I think I do to retrieve the property name.  But once I have the property name of the type T, how do I retrieve the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way of doing this (with winforms) is via `TypeDescriptor`; this allow you to use things `DataTable` the same as classes; the "full" pattern is quite complex (and involves checking for `IListSource`, `ITypedList`, etc; however, the short version is; to get the available properties:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
```

To get a named property:

```
PropertDescriptor prop = props[propName];
```

To get a value for an instance (`sourceObject`):

```
object val = prop.GetValue(sourceObject);
```

To render a value as a string (using the designated converter):

```
string s = prop.Converter.ConvertToString(val);
```

Comment: is this the same as doing obj.GetType().GetProperty("Surname").GetValue(obj, null) ?

Comment: Not quite; importantly, it takes custom models (via (`TypeDescriptionProvider`) into account. To get **full** support (for custom `ITypedList` etc) you need extra work, but it means that if you *do* need to support this, you don't have to rewrite everything. It will also support things like HyperDescriptor without any changes ;-p

Answer (score 2):

You could limit T to an interface, and use that interface in the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

What does T represent ?
Like it is now, it is a generic type and it can be ... anything.

So, what I would do, is create an interface `IListViewBindable` or something like that.  That interface could then have a method '`CreateListViewItem`' for instance.

Then, I would change the method, so that a constraint is applied to your type-parameter T, saying that T should implement `IListViewBindable`, like this:

```
public void BindDataToListView<T>( List<T> containerItems ) where T : IListViewBindable
{}
```

In your BindDataToListView method, you could then do this:

```
foreach( T item in containerItems )
{
    this.Items.Add (item.CreateListViewItem());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the items in the list are of totally unconstrained type, then you can treat them as simply of type `object`. You call `GetType()` to get the type of the object. On that you can call `GetProperties()` to get an array of `PropertyInfo` objects. And on those you can call `GetValue()` to retrieve the value of the property.

If you already know the name of a property, just call `GetProperty()` to retrieve it:

```
string valueAsString = item.GetType().GetProperty("Something")
                         .GetValue(item, null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you're asking, but I think that this will point you in the right direction. Please ask for clarification if it looks like it can help and it's unclear.

You can access a given property of an object using reflection via

```
object o;
PropertyInfo info = o.GetType().GetProperty().GetProperty("NameOfPropertyIWant");
```

and you can get the value via

```
object value = info.GetValue(o, null);
```

Now, if you're going to be accessing a property of the same name on objects of various types, you should consider adding an interface

```
public interface IHasThePropertyIWant {
    object NameOfPropertyIWant { get; }
}
```

Then you can enforce this via

```
void BindDataToListView(List<T> containerItems) where T : IHasThePropertyIWant
```

and use it in the look like so

```
foreach (T item in containerItems) {
    object o = item.NameOfPropertyIWant;
    // do something with o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) uses reflection to do exactly what you are trying to do: populate a ListView using reflection. You could save yourself a lot of trouble by using it. It has already solved all the tricky problems you are going to encounter on this path.

If you really, really want to do it yourself, Marc's answer is (of course) completely correct.